# Python SQlite select query returning list instead of integer

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a function to query DB and return a value like below

```
def find_dase(Plants):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("dexro.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(("SELECT Years FROM Plants_no WHERE Plant=?"),(Plants,))
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return data
```

when i execute this i am getting a list instead of the value

```
print(find_dase('dex'))
print(type(find_dase('dex')))
```

**Output:**

```
[('10',)]      
<class 'list'>
```

How can i fetch only the integer value

Comment: Can you use `.fetchone()` instead `.fetchall()`?

Comment: it gives <class 'tuple'>

Comment: Yes, it returns a row, in this case the row contains only one value, `Years`. So `.fetchone()[0]`

Comment: Thanks, this works

Comment: No problem, I wrote answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cursor.fetchall()` fetches all rows in form of list. In this case the row has only one value `Year`, so list of one valued tuples.

Solution:

Use `.fetchone()` to fetch only one row in form of `tuple` and index it:

```
def find_dase(Plants):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("dexro.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(("SELECT Years FROM Plants_no WHERE Plant=?"),(Plants,))
    data = cursor.fetchone()[0]  # THIS IS CHANGED
    conn.close()
    return data
```